# Why do I get a AttrributeError on this bit of code?

Tags: python, discord.py

I get the error,"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'" when I run the following line of code:
How do I fix this?

```
    if now.weekday() == 3:
        if thursday_lunch_time.shift(minutes=1).time() > now.time() > thursday_lunch_time.time():
            print(f"Got channel {channel}")
            await channel.send(random.choice(list_warning))
            await asyncio.sleep(65)
```

Comment: Please post the whole error message, with full traceback, and all the relevant portions of your code (including the part that sets `channel`).

Comment: Alright, sorry for the rushed post.

Answer (score 1):

**The bot can not get the channel so its None and you're doing `channel.send` means `None.send` which is why you get that error**

Make sure the bot has permissions to read messages for that channel and you pass in the correct channel ID or channel Name.